# Network data/bandwidth accounting on a VM's network from the host/hypervisor side (libvirt/KVM, bridged networking)

Tags: kvm-virtualization, bridge, libvirt, bandwidth-measuring

On a server a few KVM/libvirt virtual machines are running.  Sometimes these use lots of GB in network bandwidth.  I would like to do statistics on network transfers (bandwidth usage, ideally by IP address) in order to rule out foul play (e.g. data exfiltration or flood/DoS attacks).

Is there a way to collect bandwidth data on the KVM/libvirt hypervisor/host side?

The network is currently bridged (without NAT), each VM has its own IP address.

Comment: Each VM has a vnetX adapter on the host, you can see the ingress/egress counters there

Comment: @dyasny OK, how would I go about getting statistics (more than total bytes sent/received since last boot which I already have)?

Comment: iftop, nload, nethogs, iptraf, the list goes on and on really